# SQL Agent - PowerShell step “syntax error”

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell block that runs fine in the PowerShell window but when I put the same exact code into SQL Server Agent job step and try to execute it it failed with the following message.

```
Date              27.6.2015 1:00:00
Log               Job History (JobName)
Step ID            1
Server             ServerName
Job Name           JobName
Step Name          Step1
Duration           00:00:00
Sql Severity       0
Sql Message ID     0
Operator Emailed        
Operator Net sent       
Operator Paged      
Retries Attempted   0
```

Message

> Unable to start execution of step 1 (reason: line(46): Syntax error). 
>   The step failed.

Below is the offending code

```
$text = $table | Where-Object {$_.Pending_Messages -gt $threshold} | Out-String 
$html = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""  ""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd""><html xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml""><head>$style</head><body>$name <br />$warning<br /><br /><table><tr><td>Pending_Messages</td><td>Transaction Profile ID</td><td>Description</td><td>name</td><td>Last Activity</td><td>Address</td><td>Minimum Sent Time</td><td>Awake</td></tr>"
foreach ($Row in $table.Rows) { 
  if ($($Row[0]) -gt $threshold) { # <--- This is line 46
    $ToSend = 1
    write-host "value is : $($Row[0])"
    $html += "<tr><td>" + $row[0] + "</td><td>" + $row[1] + "</td><td>" + $row[2] + "</td><td>" + $row[3] + "</td><td>" + $row[4] + "</td><td>" + $row[5] + "</td><td>" + $row[6] + "</td><td>" + $row[7] + "</td></tr>"
    #break
  }
}
```

What went wrong?

Comment: @authprivate: please do not edit and change clearly non-code text into `this form`. Code ticks are supposed to be for code only, and not for `powershell`, for example.

Comment: Doubt is has _anything_ to do with the problem but `if ($($Row[0]) -gt $threshold)` could just be `if ($Row[0] -gt $threshold)`. Possibly `$Row[0]` is being treated as a string?  `if ([int]($Row[0]) -gt $threshold)`

Comment: I would recommend using `$table.Rows | Where { $_[0] -gt $threshold } | Foreach-Object { $Row = $_; <# loop iteration code #> }`. Not sure if it would solve the problem, but the `foreach` keyword is synchronous, while the pipeline is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't said what version of SQL Server or Windows OS you're running, but [the Agent runs its own version of powershell](http://www.travisgan.com/2013/05/sql-server-agent-job-and-powershell.html) that's distinct from whatever you may have installed.

> On SQL Server 2012, sqlps utility launches PowerShell 2.0
>
> On SQL Server 2008/2008R2, sqlps utility launches PowerShell 1.0

So, you may be using a syntax feature that's only available in a later version of powershell than what your Agent is running, which is why you get the Syntax error message.

Comment: Thank you dpw and also thanks to all who have made comments. It's good to know that the agent run it's own version of powershell. What i found is that culprit is $() syntax.